# Trying to get element by class name VBA Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount and the text within that says 20.00

I Have tried various means such as findelementbyclass which is not supported because it is a compound.

I am currently trying to get it to work with findelementbycss and I get a no such element error.

```html
<div class="summary entry-summary">
        <div class="summary-container"><h2 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">2&#8243;x 2&#8243; Alumi-guard fence END post for 4&#8242; tall fence</h2>
<p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>20.00</bdi></span></p>
<div class="avada-availability">
    </div>
<div class="product-border fusion-separator sep-none"></div>
```

```
Private driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub test2()

Dim name As String

name = "test"
Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Dim By As New By, variableName As WebElement

driver.Start "chrome"

driver.Get "https://www.kandmfence.net/product/2x-2-alumi-guard-fence-end-post-for-4-tall-fence/"

variableName = driver.FindElementByCss(".woocommerce-Price-amount .amount")

Sheet1.Cells.Value = variableName.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to remove the space `.FindElementByCss(".woocommerce-Price-amount.amount")`

Comment: it will still say "object var or with block var not set"

Comment: You have forgotten to use `SET variableName =driver.FindElementByCss(".woocommerce-Price-amount.amount")`

Comment: it now errors on the next line-Sheet1.Cells.Value = variableName.Text
it says "application defined or object defined error"

Comment: Yes you need to assign to a single cell e.g. cells(1,1)

Comment: got it. For any future newbies: Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = variableName.Text.

thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetPrice()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.kandmfence.net/product/2x-2-alumi-guard-fence-end-post-for-4-tall-fence/"
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument
    
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "Get", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    MsgBox Html.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount > [class$='currencySymbol']").NextSibling.NodeValue

End Sub
```

Prints:

```
20.00
```

In case the above fails because of different excel versions, try the following:

```
Html.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount").innerText
```

Before running the above script, be sure to add the following reference to the library:

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: It will give an compile error when running the above and say "user-defined type not defined",

I am trying to get the price from the page and insert into excel.

when using the html.queryselector it is still saying undefined.

Comment: It's because of the variation of our excel versions. I'm using excel 2016. However, try this `Html.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount > [class$='currencySymbol']").NextSibling.NextSibling.NodeValue`. I'm not sure if it will work as I suggested it hypothetically.

Comment: Also, check out the edit @Red.

Comment: with Html.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount > [class$='currencySymbol']").NextSibling.NextSibling.NodeValue.

"it says object with block var not set"

Comment: with Html.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount").innerText

it says "invalid use of property"

Comment: Microsoft HTML Object Library is enabled

Comment: Which version of excel you are using? Among the three suggested selectors, the two are working flawlessly on my end.

Comment: With 2019 I have no issues using `Html.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount").innerText`

Comment: it is excel 365. the two edits are working, I didn't have the message box. I am trying to get it to print to the cell a1

Comment: if I try Sheet1.Cells.Value=Html.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount").innerText, it will give application defined or object defined error

Comment: @SIM and  Qharr: thank you for you help.  
 Sheet1.Cells.Cells(1, 1).Value = Html.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount").innerText

Comment: @SIM Ok, done. Sorry misread it as upvote.